# Terminal Services - Access Denied from ASMX web service

Tags: web-services, asmx, access-denied, terminal-services, wtsapi32

I'm using the [Cassia](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cassia/) library to get terminal service information on Server 2008R2. Further more, this is being called from a ASMX web service. I'm having problems with an Access Denied error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is Denied
```

I'm assuming this just means that my Application Pool needs to be added to a certain user group, but I'm not sure which one (had to do this before to read performance counters). Anyone know which?

**Update:** As I said in a comment under this post, adding the app pool to the admin group allowed the right access. However after a while (maybe a week or a few days), the access was auto deleted. Not sure if it was automatically done by some pre-included service or by another administrative user. However I don't really think this is the best way for this anyway. There's got to be a lower level group that would have access to terminal services. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like this probably need to be run as `Administrator`?

Comment: So add my application pool to the admin group?

Comment: Adding to Administrators group worked, but I wonder if this is too much access for such a thing? Any minimal group level to accomplish the same thing?